# How to get the borders of each country

Tags: python, geolocation

I am trying to get the coordinates (latitude and longitude) of the bounding polygon of each country of the world and so far I downloaded this data set
(http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php).

And I was able to retrieve the bounding polygon for each country in this way

```
import shapefile
sf = shapefile.Reader("TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.sph")
shapes = sf.shapes()

j = 0 # number of the country

lat = []; lon = []
for i in range(len(shapes[j].points)):
    lat.append(shapes[j].points[i][0]);lon.append(shapes[j].points[i][1])
```

However, I do not understand how to get the name of the country associated to each polygon.

This may be a very simple question but I really cannot find a solution.

I tried to look at the attributes of shapes, but the name of the country does not seem to be there.

The dataset I've downloaded contains a bunch of other binary files, but I don't really know how they've been written, so I was hoping somebody may be familiar with this dataset of with the shapefile library.

Comment: Yes! If I do `dir(shapes[0])` this is what I get `['__doc__', '__geo_interface__', '__init__', '__module__', 'bbox', 'parts', 'points', 'shapeType']`, but it doesn't help much.

Comment: Already did that. `shapeType` is always set to 5 and `points` are the coordinates of the bounding polygons. I have no idea what `bbox` and `parts` are, but the first one is a list of four numbers and the second one a list of two numbers. So, there's no hint of a name here. However, in the datasets I downloaded there are other files, so maybe the names are there, but they're binary files and I don't really know how they were written. I just hope somebody is familiar with this dataset and can give me some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

for me this works:

```
fname = "data/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp"
import shapefile
sf = shapefile.Reader(fname)
shapes = sf.shapeRecords()
shape = shapes[1]
print shape.record
points = shape.shape.points
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, it looks like the latitude and longitude coordinates are reversed.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Jun  2 21:22:58 2021

@author: yrtst
"""

    import shapefile
    fname = r'D:\222\444\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp'
    sf = shapefile.Reader(fname,resolution='h')
    shapes = sf.shapes()

    j = 29# number of the country

    lat = []; lon = []
    for i in range(len(shapes[j].points)):
        lat.append(shapes[j].points[i][1]);lon.append(shapes[j].points[i][0])

    print(lat[2000])
    print(lon[2000])




    #Guess the countires!

    #First find the approximate range of the coordinates of a country's border. 
    #Then traverse all the border data to find the intersection.

    #Take China's latitude and longitude range as an example.


    import shapefile
    fname = r'D:\222\444\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp'
    sf = shapefile.Reader(fname,resolution='h')
    shapes = sf.shapes()
    j=0
    possible_lat=[]
    possilbe_lon=[]
    while j<246:

        lat = []; lon = []
        for i in range(len(shapes[j].points)):
            lat.append(shapes[j].points[i][1]);lon.append(shapes[j].points[i][0])
            #print(lat)
            #print(lon)
            #ll=[lat,lon]
            #print(lon)


        #the approximate range of the latitude
        for check_lat in lat:
            if 21<check_lat<24 :
                possible_lat.append(j)
                break

        #the approximate range of the longitude
        for check_lon in lon:
            if 130<check_lon<133 :

                possilbe_lon.append(j)
                break
   
        
        lat = []; lon = []
        j+=1    

    #The data that appears in the following two lists at the same time 
    #is the country code we are looking for.
    print(possible_lat)
    print(possilbe_lon)
```